# Arquitectura en N capas

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, entity-framework, arquitectura

reedito la pregunta para adaptarla a los consejos que se me han dado.

En primer lugar, me hallo en la construcción de una API REST en ASP.NET y estoy usando la arquitectura 'N' capas, he optado por tener la capa del controlador, una capa que he llamado "servicios" donde se incluye la lógica de negocio y una capa llamada "data" donde se incluye el acceso a base de datos.

Las clases data crean su propio contexto para trabajar con los datos como se ve aquí:

```
 public class EmpleadoData
{
    private EmpresaEntity context;
    public EmpleadoData()
    {
        context = new EmpresaEntity();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Empleado> ObtenerEmpleados()
    {
        return context.Empleado.ToList();
    }
}
```

Mi problema es que cuando obtengo los datos en la capa servicios y quiero añadir su id a un objeto nuevo que voy a crear, como son dos contextos distintos, me da un error.

Y mi pregunta es, si es esta la forma correcta de arquitectura en N capas o estoy cometiendo algún error.

Como siempre, después de leer los comentarios intentare realizar las actualizaciones necesarias y si hiciera falta añadir la información que se necesite, muchas gracias por los comentarios.

Un saludo.

Comment: Parece basada en opiniones

Comment: Investiga el patron UoW (unit of work), este te permitira realizar varias operaciones que ejecuten en una unica transaccion

Comment: Aunque mi comentario pueda ser considerado basado en opiniones, te convendría antes aprender TDD y aprender un poco más a fondo patrones de diseño (GOF) para que puedas identificar mejor con el coste y limitaciones para que puedas adicionar un patrón de diseño a tu proyecto con éxito y conseguir lo que necesitas. Resumen Nivel 5: sin entrar en mucho detalle para que podás usar un solo objeto a nivel de toda la aplicación se usa el patrón Singleton. Te recomiendo que investigues más a fondo esto. Espero que te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Pedir esas cosas en este sitio no es valido. Las preguntas tienen que tener una respuesta que tampoco sea basada en opiniones.

Answer (score -3):

Puedes implementar el patrón unidad de carga. Lo encuentras en la documentación oficial de Microsoft:

[Patrón unidad de carga](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/infrastructure-persistence-layer-design)

[Patrón repositorio y unidad de carga](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/architecture/patterns/)

Comment: Responder con solo enlaces se considera de baja calidad

Comment: Que pena, no sabia. Le sugiero a la persona que pregunta que revise la documentación compartida en los links. Creo que con dicha información es suficiente para que implemente lo que preguntó. ¿Cómo son las respuestas de alta calidad para tenerlo en cuenta en la próxima?

Comment: Aquí tu respuesta lee [answer]; además checa el [tour]

Comment: ¿No aplica lo mismo? ¿Baja calidad?

Comment: Aunque la pregunta se considera basada en opiniones y lo mas probable es que termine cerrada, tene en cuenta que la respuesta tiene que ser completa y clara, y no una lista de enlaces. Revisa [answer]. De paso, tambien hace el [tour] para que sepas como funcionamos. Esta clase de respuestas suelen terminar eliminadas. Si necesitas hacer cambios en la misma, apreta el boton [edit]

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus aclaraciones. La próxima vez responderé con los estándares exigidos por stackoverflow.